# Export Access report to PDF Fillable Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, export

Id like to populate an Adobe Fillable form using data pulled from an Access report. I would appreciate some advice on how to get this code to work. I am relatively new to VBA, so my biggest question would come from which part of the code are Adobe, and which part are from Access fields.

Some of my field names for access are: Payee Extended_Payee, Check Request Date, Invoice Number, etc. 
Some of my field names in the Adobe form are:Payee, Today's Date, Invoice Number, etc.

This is the coding I have so far - I would just like clarification on which part of the code should reflect the adobe fields and which part should be from Access
:

```
   Private Sub Export_Click()

Dim FileNm, gApp, avDoc, pdDoc, jso

FileNm = "M:\Check_Requests\2017\PDF_Exports\CheckForm.pdf" 'File location
Set gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.app")

Set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
FileCopy FileNm, newFileNm
If avDoc.Open(newFileNm, "") Then
    Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Payee[0]").Value = "Payees_Extended_Payee"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Address[0]").Value = "Address"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].City[0]").Value = "City"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].State[0]").Value = "State"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Zip_Code[0]").Value = "Zip_Code"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Comments_to_Include_on_Remittance[0]").Value = "Description_of_Expense"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Todays_Date[0]").Value = "Check_Request_Date"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Invoice_Number[0]").Value = "Invoice_Number"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Invoice_Date[0]").Value = "Invoice_Date"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Total_Amount[0]").Value = "Total_Amount"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Description_of_Expense[0]").Value = "Description_of_Expense"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Other[0]").Value = "Other"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].GL1[0]").Value = "GL_Company"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AU1[0]").Value = "Accounting Unit"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].A1[0]").Value = "Account"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].CODE1[0]").Value = "Project_Code"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AMOUNT1[0]").Value = "Amount_Split_1"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].GL2[0]").Value = "GL_Company_2"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AU2[0]").Value = "Accounting_Unit_2"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].A2[0]").Value = "Account_2"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].CODE2[0]").Value = "Project_Code_2"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AMOUNT2[0]").Value = "Amount_Split_2"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].GL3[0]").Value = "GL_Company_3"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AU3[0]").Value = "Accounting_Unit_3"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].A3[0]").Value = "Account_3"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].CODE3[0]").Value = "Project_Code_3"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AMOUNT3[0]").Value = "Amount_Split_3"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Total[0]").Value = "Amount_Total"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Requestor[0]").Value = "Requestor"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Approving Manager[0]").Value = "Approving_Manager"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Extension[0]").Value = "Extension"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Email_Address[0]").Value = "Email_Address"
    pdDoc.Save PDSaveIncremental, FileNm 'Save changes to the PDF document
    pdDoc.Close
    End If
'Close the PDF; the True parameter prevents the Save As dialog from showing
avDoc.Close (True)

'Some cleaning
Set gApp = Nothing
Set avDoc = Nothing
Set pdDoc = Nothing
Set jso = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a function that creates and runs instance of AcroExch.app, opens PDF document referenced by variable `FileNm`, finds form in it, fills it with values and than saves it. All code is executed by Access.

This is the "Adobe specific" code because it depends on API of `AcroExch.AVDoc`:

```
If avDoc.Open(FileNm, "") Then
    Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Payee_Extended_Payee[0]").Value = "Payee Extended_Payee"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Address[0]").Value = "Mailing Address"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].City[0]").Value = "Mailing Address"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].State[0]").Value = "Mailing Address"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Zip_Code[0]").Value = "Mailing Address"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Description_of_Expense[0]").Value = "Comments to Include on Remin"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Check_Request_Date[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Invoice_Number[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Invoice_Date[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Total_Amount[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Other[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].GL1[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AU1[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].A1[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AMOUNT1[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].GL2[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AU2[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].A2[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AMOUNT2[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].GL3[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AU3[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].A3[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].AMOUNT3[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Amount_Total[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Requestor[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Approving Manager[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Extension[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    jso.getField("CheckForm[0].Page1[0].Email_Address[0]").Value = "Installer_or_Owner"
    pdDoc.Save PDSaveIncremental, FileNm 'Save changes to the PDF document
    pdDoc.Close
    End If
'Close the PDF; the True parameter prevents the Save As dialog from showing
avDoc.Close (True)
```

Values in fields are set by expression:

```
jso.getField("FormName[0].Page1[0].FieldName[0]").Value = NewValue
```

where `FormName` is the name of form in PDF document, `FieldName` - name of field in the form and `NewValue` - value to fill in this field.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding Alexander! I apologize, but I just want to make sure I'm clear. Do I need to change anything with my code at the beginning then? I do want to be able to click a button on an Access report, that opens a PDF form template, fills in all the data from the report, and then saves as a file specific to that invoice [Payee Payee_Extended] + [Invoice_Number] + [Check_Request_Date]

Comment: It looks like you are doing it right for me except that on every click you fill and save the same pdf file. To edit new file you must copy file to the new location/name and than open it from there. You may just add 
`FileCopy FileNm, newFileNm` before Open and then open new file with
`If avDoc.Open(newFileNm, "") Then`

Comment: I keep getting help up at the first get field. I'm wondering if it's because the Access report is set by a tempvars? Would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: For correct work of `jso.getField` there must be form with given name in PDF document and in form there must be a field with given name. In your case for first get there must be form with name `CheckForm` and field with name `Payee_Extended_Payee` in it.

Comment: Can you show me an example of the code you'd use for the newfile? This is giving me an error: Set avDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
FileCopy FileNm, newFileNm
If avDoc.Open(newFileNm, "") Then
    Set pdDoc = avDoc.GetPDDoc()
    Set jso = pdDoc.GetJSObject

Comment: That is what I believe i have. PDF file name is "CheckForm.pdf". Field in the PDF form is "Payee", and the field in Access that I want to pull into the PDF Form, is "Payee Extended_Payee". I updated my original code to reflect what I currently have. Still getting error message.